# Active Collab API - URL Structure Self Hosted

Tags: api, activecollab

I'm trying to use the [Active Collab API](https://developers.activecollab.com/api-documentation/) to retain project information for reporting purposes. I basically just want to make a daily API call and safe the JSON for further reporting in another tool.
For this reason I don't want to use an SDK or anything, just a plain API call to retain the data.

Can someone please guide me because I couldn't find the correct url structure for a self-hosted system.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with the help from the support.

First you have to obtain a token like this:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://YOUR.SITE/api/v1/issue-token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
"username" : "YOUR EMAIL",
"password" : "YOUR PASSWORD",
"client_name" : "xxx",
"client_vendor" : "xxx"
}'
```

And in the next step you can use the API as documented here by calls like this one:

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://YOUR.SITE/api/v1/projects' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'X-Angie-AuthApiToken: YOUR TOKEN'
```